# let T and T' be two topologies and T is strictly finer than T'. what does first countability one of those imply about first countability of other?

Tags: general-topology

I try to find a relation between two topology 
 when one is strictly finer than other. likewise compactness connectedness

Answer (score 2):

No.

Example 1. $(X,T')$ is any non-first countable space and $(X,T)$ is a discrete (and hence a first countable space).

Example 2. $(X,T')$ is a unit disk $\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: x^2+y^2\le 1\}$ endowed with the standard topology and $(X,T)$ we consider as a quotient space of the space of disjoint union of all its radii $\{[(0,0),(\cos\varphi,\sin\varphi)]:0\le\varphi<2\pi\}$ in which we glued together all its centers $(0,0)$.

Comment: By "a unit circle" do you mean $S^1$ or $\overline{B^2}$?

Comment: @DuncanRamage Thanks. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ is finer than $T'$ then:

- $T compact \implies T' compact$
- $T connected \implies T' connected$
- Every function that is continuous for $T$ will be continuous for $T'$

Verification should be immediate using the set-theoretic definitions of compacteness, connectedness and continuity.